# I unable to find most of the Hebrew entities to include in my HTML coding

Tags: html-entities, hebrew

I could not find the most of the hebrew characters, my client wants to include all the characters as text not an image in HTML. is that possible to find out all the characters list anywhere. please advice.

I could not show the image as example, need reputation to include.

Comment: Try uploading the image to some hosting website, e.g. http://imgur.com, and share the link.

Comment: here is a list of all the Hebrew characters: א ב ג ד ה ו ז ח ט י כ ך ל מ ם נ ן ס ע פ ף צ ץ ק ר ש ת

Comment: I have uploaded the image in imgur.com (name: bebrew.jpg). Characters present in the image wasn't found anywhere.

Comment: Please share a link to your imgur.com upload.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_HTML_for_the_Hebrew_alphabet) for the complete list of Hebrew Unicode character codes. If you specifically want to use entities, then insert the characters as `&#xNNNN;` to your HTML code - for example, use `&#x05D0;` for the letter Alef.

Comment: In that list i couldn't find the characters which are i expected Vadim

Comment: what characters were you missing?